# Why does Maven create two jars for same source in target and groupId directory

Tags: java, maven, jar, target

I have a Maven project with the `src` and `pom` having following `groupId` and `artifactId`

```xml
<groupId>com.useless.coders</groupId>
<artifactId>nonsense-program</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Now when we build the jar using `mvn clean install`, a target folder is created with the jar name and version as `nonsense-program-0.0.1` . When I navigate to `.m2` repository in the folder structure `com/useless/coders/` I can see the same jar is also created with extra metadata information in `maven-metadata-local.xml`. I know the purpose of Maven repository and as in `target` directory we house all output of the build with generated `.class` files with jar and/or libs.

But I am curious to know why we maintain two jar copies of same source one in `target` directory and other in the `groupId` path directory. Wouldn't have we saved some space.

Comment: the one at `target` to be used on your current project, the one at `.m2` to be used as dependency of other projects that might need it.

Comment: Yeah that''s correct but in any case the other projects wont use my target directory right ? and i can always fetch the jar from the groupId path.

Comment: correct, other projects will only use the jar available under the `.m2` directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you instructed Maven to do so. If you call `mvn clean package` (instead of `install`), only the Jar under `target` is created. The `install` phase tells Maven to save the resulting Jar in the local repository.

Comment: That Right , i meant to say that when we instruct `mvn clean install` we are maintaining the same jar copies , whether putting it in target wouldn't make much diffrence

Comment: As already mentioned by @Salvador the `target` folder is used by other projects which might be existing if you have mutli module build. And furthermore you can control which state of your project could be used by other project (independent projects) by using `mvn clean install` so they can consume the state in your local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository`.  This makes the difference.